# Page keep loading infinitly in try except statement of function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, try-except

During automating of review posting, I am stuck in a situation where a function having try-except statement. You may get my point clearly by reading below code.

This method writes reviews and return `True` or `False`

```
def write_review(browser,row):
    try:
    
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'label[for="rating-5"]'))).click()
    
        sleep(1)
        browser.find_element_by_id("review.userNickname").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_id("review.userNickname").send_keys(row['nickname'].replace(' ',''))
        sleep(1)
        browser.find_element_by_id("review.title").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_id("review.title").send_keys(row['headline'])
        sleep(1)
        browser.find_element_by_id("review.reviewText").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_id("review.reviewText").send_keys(row['review'])
        sleep(1)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for="review.netPromoterScore.10"]').click()
        sleep(1)
    
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class*="js-preview"]').click()
        sleep(3)
    
        print('Submitting a review....') 
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class*="js-submit"]'))).click()
        sleep(5)
        return True
    except Exception as ex::
        print(str(ex))
        return False
```

In case if any review is not posted successfully, I have implemented function call like this

```
browser.get(url)
success = write_review(browser,row)
if success==False:
    while success!=True:
        browser.get(url)
        print('Again submitting...')
        success = write_review(browser,row)
```

But the problem with above code is that in case of unsuccessful review posting, the page keep loading again and again without having entered any data in review body. Actually the error occurs at the line after `print('Submitting a review....')` statement which means `click` action before this line sometimes doesn't load javascript correctly. That's why I loaded that page again with the same statement of function call after `while` loop. Here are some error messages

```
Continue to review posting....
Submitting a review....
Submitting a review....
Submitting a review....
Submitting a review....
Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 5.8.0-49-generic x86_64)

Again submitting...
Message: unknown error: Element <label for="rating-5" class="">...</label> is not clickable at point (468, 17). Other element would receive the click: <input id="search-autocomplete" type="text" name="query" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Search food, toys, prescriptions and more" role="combobox" aria-controls="search__suggestions" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-label="Search food, toys, prescriptions and more" class="sfw-search__input">
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 5.8.0-49-generic x86_64)

Again submitting...
Message: unknown error: Element <label for="rating-5" class="">...</label> is not clickable at point (468, 18). Other element would receive the click: <input id="search-autocomplete" type="text" name="query" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Search food, toys, prescriptions and more" role="combobox" aria-controls="search__suggestions" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-label="Search food, toys, prescriptions and more" class="sfw-search__input">
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 5.8.0-49-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Why did you loop it then?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan the error occurs at the line after `print('Submitting a review....')` statement which means `click` action before this line sometimes doesn't load javascript correctly. That's why I loaded that page again with the same statement of function call after `while` loop

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I just added error stack with some more detail.

Comment: Why did you put sleep after WebDriverWait? Why do you return something here?

Comment: Try what I suggested

Answer (score 1):

Place print/log inside 'except' block with exception info message and check why exceptions keep rising. Muting any exception especially global without logging error message is really bad idea.

Example:

```
    try:
        # Your code
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        return False
```

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. Actually the error occurs at the line after `print('Submitting a review....')` statement which means `click` action before this line sometimes doesn't load javascript correctly. That's why I loaded that page again with the same statement of function call after `while` loop

Comment: I also added error stack with more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent a infinite loop,you can try this

```
browser.get(url)
success = write_review(browser,row)
if success==False:
    trytimes = 0
    maxtrytimes = 10
    while success!=True:
        browser.get(url)
        print('Again submitting...')
        success = write_review(browser,row)
        trytimes+=1
        if trytimes>maxtrytimes:
            print("write_review failed too many times")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the button:
Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Add wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".a[class="js-submit"]")))
list_view = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class="js-submit"]')
list_view.click()
```

You are using `presence_of_element_located` but it will not wait for the button completely.
Next, remove loop and remove sleeps.
Replace all sleeps with explicit wait like mentioned above, that will wait for the element that takes most time to load. Use `EC.visibility_of_element_located` to wait for an element to become visible.

You are ddosing the form because some locators are not completely loaded or some locators are incorrect. `time.sleep(1)` before each input is a very bad solution.
And finally, check if `a[class="js-submit"]` is unique.